# Make glossary defined terms bold

Tags: glossaries, bold

I have defined a lot of terms with the `glossaries` package and use them in my text with the `\gls{}` command. However, I'd like terms called with `\gls{}` to appear bold, so people know that it is a term defined in the glossary.
What command do I have to renew and how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `glossaries` package offers the command `\glstextformat` to control the way the text is displayed, so you can write

```
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
```

or

```
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}{\textbf}
```

in the preamble of your document.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I am using the glossaries package, didn't know that there was a previous version.

Comment: or even `\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}{\textbf}` which is even preferable, albeit a little hard to digest for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether `\gls` is your command or an external one, to whose definition you don't have easy access.  If the latter, then you can do something like

```
\let\oldgls=\gls
\renewcommand\gls[1]{\textbf{\oldgls{#1}}}
```

(This sort of manipulation can be automated using [patch](http://ctan.org/pkg/patch).)  If the former, then, rather than devoting a new command to it, you can just replace your definition

```
\newcommand\gls[1]{...}
```

by

```
\newcommand\gls[1]{\textbf{...}}
```

Comment: Oops, sorry, I missed the fact that you were using a specific package.  My answer is about general fiddling with commands after their definition; G Medina's answer (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21152/make-glossary-defined-terms-bold/21154) is a much better approach in your specific setting.